# How to get all of the activate_plugin action parameters?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks, actions

I am trying to hook into activate_plugin.

I know that activate_plugin has 1 required param and 2 optional ones. I am trying to acquire all 3.

Here's my setup:

```
// create plugin settings menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'pe_create_menu');


function pe_create_menu() {

  //create new sub-level menu
  add_submenu_page( 'plugins.php', 'Plugin Settings', 'Plugin Enabler', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'pe_settings_page' );

  // Add my hook
  add_action( 'activate_plugin', 'pe_network_activate', 10, 3 );
}
```

And my function:

```
function pe_network_activate( $plugin, $redirect = '', $network_wide = false ) {
  $args = var_export( func_get_args(), true);
  _log("Args: " . $args); // write to the WP error_log
}
```

$args returns only the first parameter. How do I get all 3?

My goal is to be able to tell when a plugin is being network activated, or just normally activated - hence the need for $network_wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `activate_plugin()` function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L466) accepts three parameters, but it emits the `activate_plugin` action with only one parameter. This can be confusing, but hooks sometimes use the same name as the function they come from, without passing the same parameters.

One way to get the difference between a network activation and a regular activation is to monitor the `update_site_option` and `update_option` hooks. Only one of them will fire, depending on the `$network_wide` parameter of `activate_plugin()`.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need `var_export()` for? `func_get_args()` should give you array of arguments on its own.

Comment: I was following example 2 from the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) of how to use it. I wanted to see what I was getting. Editted my post to make that a bit more clear.